# How to remove textbox css style from input[type='text']

Tags: css, asp.net

In my whole application i have globally declared textbox style as in css

```
input[type='text'], input[type=password], textarea { //My styles }
```

I need to remove this style from search textbox

```
<input id="txtSerach" type="text" placeholder="Search here..." required />
```

Comment: you have a unique `ID` on this input, use it and reset those properties what you don't want on this.

Answer (score 2):

```
input[type='text']:not(#txtSearch), input[type=password], textarea { //My styles }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is HTML5 you can also use input type="search" and use different css for all search fields

```
<input id="txtSerach" type="search" placeholder="Search here..." required />
```